# Umbraco contour on azure fails when form is submitted

Tags: sql, azure, umbraco, azure-sql-database, umbraco-contour

I have installed my Umbraco site on Azure and this is working beautifully. I installed Contour on my Umbrcaco system which I did manually in order to successfully install the database. The whole form admin seems fine and the form I have created displays fine until I submit it, I get the following error:

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of
>   SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

I have searched high and low and can't find a solution to this problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately... this is, indeed, a limitation of SQL-Azure. You'll need to do what it says and create a clustered index on each table.

Details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#cir